# can you reduce the order of an equality expression with infinite groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

I have $G \cong R^3$ and $Z(G) \cong \mathbb{R}$ (the whole process up until here is omitted for shortness)

It can be easily shown that $G \cong \mathbb{R}^3$ thus $|G| = |\mathbb{R}^3|$

We know that $|G| = |G/Z(G)||Z(G)|$ and we showed that $|Z(G)| = |\mathbb{R}|$

Thus $|\mathbb{R}^3|=|G/Z(G)||\mathbb{R}|$ so it must be that $|G/Z(G)| = |\mathbb{R}^2|$

I am not sure if the above is correct, and if it is I would like to know at leas the intuition of how to prove it (the result is correct, the method may be wrong)

Comment: I’m guessing that you are using the absolute-value bars to denote cardinality. If this is right, *all* your cardinalities are continuum, i.e. all are equal to each other. (Not too useful.)

Comment: I am using them to denote order

Comment: For finite groups, “order” equals “cardinality”. If you’re talking order, you’re certainly talking cardinality.